# When should we use "these ones" vs "those ones"?

Tags: pronouns, british-english, australian-english, canadian-english

When we are talking about things we can say "**these** ones" or **those** ones". What is the difference in fact?

For example if I want to point with a index finger on two things, should I say "those ones" or "these ones", the same question about a case in which I am talking in front of students as a lecturer and I want to say that "those/these who want to get more marks should know a bonus chapter in the book".

Comment: Could you add definitions of "these" and "those? A dictionary might solve this.

Comment: Please, according to Babilon dictionary: "These: pronoun used to indicate several specific people or things". "Those. pronoun used to indicate specific people or objects".

Comment: I'd look for a better dictionary.

Comment: "these = plural of this", "those = plural of that"

Comment: Then we come to question what is the difference between "it", this" and that", I am always confused with it/ this /that.

Comment: Does this help:  "th**is** is here", "th**at** at there"?

Comment: If the question is about *these ones* and *those ones*, I think it's a great question, because they are used in British, Australian & Canadian English; but not so much in American English. If the question is about *these* and *those*, which it seems to be  given the answer you selected  then it's a question solvable by looking in any online dictionary.

Comment: It's about those one and these ones, and the answer which selected answer on it. "these ones" should refer to these which near, while those ones refer to those that are farther.

Comment: @Assiduous I do not know why on earth this question was closed. It's a great question. Let's see if we can get you an answer. One thing I *do* know: none of the close voters could answer this question! ;-)

Comment: You're right;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These and those](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/that-these-and-those) are the plurals of this and that.

We mainly use **these** to talk about something closer, and **those** to talk about something that is further away.

We can use **this** but not **these** to introduce people, or to introduce your self on the phone, or to talk about things happening now:

> Hello, **this** is Jane
>
> Everything is so expensive **these** days

and you can use **that** or **those** to refer to something that happened in the past.

> Things were simpler in **those** days

We can also use **these** to be emphatic about something.

> No, **these** are the ones I want

and **those** to talk about something that is unimportant:

> Leave **those**, we can deal with them tomorrow

or even to be dismissive about something:

> I did not have sex with **that** woman [Bill Clinton, 1998](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/special_report/1998/12/98/review_of_98/themes/208715.stm)

Comment: The question seems to me to be asking about *these ones* and *those ones*, and marginally about *these* and *those*. The former pair are not widespread among speakers of American English.

Answer (score 2):

*Partial answer.*

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/), *these* is the plural form of *this*, and *those* is the plural form of *that*.

> [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/this)
>   1 a (1) :  the person, thing, or idea that is present or near in place, time, or thought or that has just been mentioned
>
> [that](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that)
>   2
>   a :  the one farther away or less immediately under observation or discussion

So *those ones* refers to things away from you; *these ones* refers to things close to you.

Let's suppose *ones* are *apples*, and there are some apples next to you, and there are some apples away from you.
You point to the apples close to you and say

> I like *these* apples.

You point to the apples away from you and say

> I do not like *those* apples.

Next, it should be

> **Those**/<strike>these</strike> who want to get more marks should know a bonus chapter in the book

I cannot explain why. I think it is because the students are sitting *away* from you, or that you are referring to people away from you.

If you had a cage full of students and you were standing next to the cage and you point to the students in the cage, it might make sense to say

> these who want to get more marks should know a bonus chapter in the book

But I admit, this sounds very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, if you can touch the things or persons with your finger, even if you have to stretch to touch them, you use *this* and *these*, otherwise you use *that* and *those*. Note that *these ones* and *those ones* are used by many who speak British English, Canadian English &  Australian English,  but not American English. In AmE we say *these* or *those*. For this,   see [Mailbag Friday: These ones](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/mailbag-friday-these-ones/) and Canadian TV.